# Why does Android OS consume my network transfer?

Tags: networking, system

The app data usage section of the Settings mentions that "Android OS" has taken transferred 1.73 MB of data in the background.

What is that caused by? I have disabled captive portal detection on my device. I'm running CM 13.0 without Play Services.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed on my CM13 phone, I will periodically get notifications when there are new nightlies out.  Have you tried disabling the automatic checks for updates?  Simply go to Settings->About phone->CyanogenMod updates->Check for updates-> Set to 'manual'.

Comment: I have a weekly check for updates, so I guess it's not that. After connecting to a cellular network, though, 200B was transferred by the Android OS, even though the last check had been the day before.